# Continuous Integration recommendation for a single private repo Android project hosted on GitHub

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration

I've decided it's time to set up proper CI (I've upwards of 9000 unit tests now, [which still run very fast locally]) and integrate it into my GitHub hosted private repo. The project is an Android project (so requires Android SDK etc to run tests).

I originally went with TravisCI and was blown away by the 129/mo they ask for a single private project.

I was wondering what others in the community are using and have found useful for similarly scoped small but not open source Android projects. Must be cheaper than TravisCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a service, rather than software, I would suggest taking a look at [Circle-CI](https://circleci.com)

- Current pricing - 1 Linux container *You can run 1 concurrent build with 1 container 1x parallelism 1500 build minutes/month* ***Free*** Then each additional container $50/month with no build minutes limits.
- Containers can run both build and tests
- Pre-configured containers with the Android SDK pre-installed
- I found their documentation clear and uncluttered.

Comment: thanks! what do you  think of drone.io? that's something i've also been eyeing...

Comment: @Creos I honestly haven't tried it

Comment: i tried Circle-CI and i liked it a lot more than jenkins, and it is completely free for a single container (and integrates seamlessly with github private repo). it did take me a bit to fiddle with the build config for an android project but nothing you cannot solve with some googleing and trial-and-error. thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look at [Jenkins CI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Home) *formerly Hudson* which has the following characteristics:

- Free, **Gratis** & Open Sourced, MIT Licence
- Java based so cross platform
- If your builds/tests can be run from the server command line then they can run from Jenkins
- Distributed builds available
- Version control system integration for SVN, git, hg, etc.
- Scheduled, on change or on demand runs
- Available in docker containers or vagrant boxes so your build/test machine(s) can be containerised.
- **lots** of plug-ins including reporting tools
- Web interface + APIs
- Widely used and lots of help/support available

Comment: ok thanks, i'll look into it... i've used it in the past in a professional environment and my impression of jenkins was that's it's an unwieldy behemoth and kind of... for lack of a better word crappy. however, my impression was pretty superficial and it was some time ago so i'll definitely look into it. thx for the reply, since it's the only one i'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @Creos - Jenkins is definitely a "Swiss army knife" but then again unless you are producing a single, highly specialised, custom solution that is to some extent inevitable. It __has__ to be able to do anything. You could probably come up with a much simpler CI system for your specific usage, say a couple of python scripts that checked out multiple copies, did all the builds, ran the tests, etc., but the time spent on it would exceed the time learning & configuring Jenkins.